# Dojox - mvc : How to get widgets declared in template?

Tags: dojo

In dojo 1.8 version, I have used this._startupWidgets to get widgets declared in template.But in dojo 1.9 version,I get this._startupwidgets as null.So I don't know that how to get it in dojo 1.9 version?

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually looking for widgets contained within the reference widget, try:

```js
var widget; // The widget you care about
require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
    registry.findWidgets(widget.domNode);
});
```

It should be noted that private variables/APIs begin with `_`.  Thus, they're subject to disappear without notice.  With that in mind, you *could* try looking at `widget._attachPoints`, which lists the names of all attach points in the template.  This will also give you the names of plain DOM nodes, not just those of attach points that refer to widgets.  A simple filter will extract those that are widgets for you:

```js
var widget; // The widget you care about
require(["dojo/_base/array"], function(array) {
    var templateWidgets = array.filter(widget._attachPoints, function(w) { 
        return !!widget[w].domNode;
    });
});
```